# How can I make this text  (slightly) more 'Chinese-looking'?

Tags: fonts

How can I make this text (slightly) more Chinese looking?

(examples will be appreciated if possible).

[image]

(I think the purpose of doing this is obvious).

**** EDIT: This is option two:**

[image]

Comment: When I think of oriental writing, I think of calligraphy. So, I would suggest a more calligriffic (I just made that word up!) look. So, vary line thickness within letters. Give that a try.

Comment: @Johannes Thanks for the tip! Can you give me some examples?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [Chinese-style font](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=201) (**edit:** changed link) but that looks gaudy and may not fit into a sleek design.

A better alternative is to look at Chinese urban environments and culture and take note of recurring sights and design elements. Neon lights, fruit baskets, smiling people, or whatever. You can use those in your logo (which doesn't need to be fully textual), to invoke the reaction you're seeking. A generic "I want a Chinese look" isn't going to make your design better.

I'm not familiar with China so I can't give specifics, but keep in mind you need to *know your audience*. Sure, you can put any random Chinese elements in your design:

[image: chinese]

But if it doesn't resonate with your specific audience, then there's no point.

Comment: Thanks for the example. My audience are foreigners asking questions about Taiwan among themselves and people from Taiwan who want to discuss with them in a forum.

Answer (score 2):

You could make it the text red, and shift the background to a brighter blue, to evoke the ROC flag.

Comment: I thought about that but I remembered that I'm anti-nationalist (anyways, some links are red).

Comment: Would red alone be better - does that denote Chinese in the more general rather than national sense?

Comment: Yes, I would probably settle with that. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

The one thing that immediately springs to mind when thinking about Taiwan is Taipei 101, formerly the world's tallest building.

My idea is maybe not 'more Chinese' in the traditional sense, but certainly in a modern sense. Your userbase will most likely recognise it immediately which is a help.

I wouldn't have thought there are any copyright issues to such a design but maybe someone who's an expert in these matters might put me straight!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why not add "Taiwan" in the Taiwanese/Chinese version of the typeface you have already?

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=201

There are tons of awesome fonts ranging from comic to professional looking ones.

Comment: I went trough them and none of them look very professional I think I just settle with Museo.

Comment: I guess its kind of subjective then. I saw some that could have been put to some use if edited.  Just goes to show how different a typeface can be perceived...